# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string', for unity dialogue parser script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting a,

> cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string' with the line
>   **string sceneNum = SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive); //”Scene1”**

Can anyone help me? I am new to scripting so I don't know how to fix this.

````
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DialogueParser: MonoBehaviour {

    List<DialogueLine> lines;
    List<Sprite> images; //images[0] refrence pose 0

    struct DialogueLine {

        public string name;
        public string content;
        public int pose;
        public string position;

    public DialogueLine(string n, string c, int p, string pos)
    {
    name = n;
    content = c;
    pose = p;
    position = pos;
    }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    string file = "Dialogue";
    string sceneNum = SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive); //”Scene1”
        sceneNum = Regex.Replace(sceneNum, "[^0-9]", ""); //"1"
    file += sceneNum; //file +sceneNum ("Dialogue1")
    file += ".txt";

        lines = new List<DialogueLine>();
        LoadDialogue(file);

        images = new List<Sprite>();
        }```
````

Answer (score 1):

> cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

As this [Unity's docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html), you can clearly see that `LoadScene` method has not any overload which returns `string` (*It means never ever this method returns string value*), so because of that, you face this error.

base on the above article, the `LoadScene` method has four overloads with two distinct dataType. these two return types are `void` and [`Scene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html). so for resolving your problem, at first you should get your scene then you can access its properties like `name`, `buildIndex` and the other properties that mentioned in the article.

```
 Scene scene = SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive); //”Scene1”

 //scene.name or scene.buildIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of method SceneManager.LoadScene as can be seen in documentation [1] returns type of void. As it means that the function doesn't return any meaningful value/information whatsoever, it  cannot be converted to your sceneNum variable of type string.

[1] https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html